# Problem understanding the definition of Quotient spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, quotient-spaces

Quotient spaces are defined as $V/U := \{a + U | a \in V\} $ where $a + U := \{a + u | u \in U\}$ U is a subspace of V, so $u \in U \implies u \in V$ and $\{a + u | a \in V\}$ = V. How does this not mean that $V/U = V$ according to the definition?

Comment: $V/U = \{a+U\,| \, a\in V\}= \{\, \{a+u:\, u\in U\} \,| \, a\in V\}$, so this is certainly not equal to $V$. Elements of $V/U$ are subsets of $V$, so elements of $V/U$ don't even have the same "type" as elements of $V$. You're right that $\{a+u| a \in V\}= V$, but how does this relate to anything? What we're interested in is $a+U$

Comment: The elements of $V/U$ are *equivalence classes of vectors* in $V$, so $V/U$ can not be equal to $V$ whose elements are vectors. Even when $U=\{0\}$ so $V/U\cong V$ we formally don't have equality, but an isomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it would help to think about the example where $V = \mathbb R^2$ and $U$ is the subspace $\{ (x,y) \mid y = x \}$. If $a \in \mathbb R^2$, then $a + U$ is a line parallel to the line $y = x$. So each element of $V/U$ is a line in $\mathbb R^2$ with slope $1$.